# How to add voice chat feature like clubhouse in react native app?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create an app like clubhouse(just for learning).
So I want to know is there any way to add voice chat like a clubhouse in react native.
I know I have to add some backend to the app.
but if anyone knows some pre-built services or some roadmap for adding this type of feature. this would be amazing for me.